# Installation LoopBack-CLI error node-gyp rebuild

Tags: installation, frameworks, loopbackjs, loopback

Hi Im installing the loopback-cli.
Running these commands:
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
AND
npm install -g loopback-cli

The second command run rebuilding the ursa module into error. There is some link to C:\OpenSSL-Win64. What the ... is this? Some hardcoded library link?

Write me please some way how to install normally the loopback. This is from their installation site. Thanx.

Here the log:

```
C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  ursaNative.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\ursaNative.cc(157): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Use
rs\Erik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(172): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Use
rs\Erik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 (node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\ursa):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ loopback-cli@4.0.0
added 3 packages and updated 1 package in 27.638s
```

Comment: I'm also facing this same problem.

Comment: `+ loopback-cli@4.0.0
added 3 packages and updated 1 package in 27.638s` Doesn't that mean it has installed successfully? Do you get any error when you run any of the CLI commands?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

**Setup before fixing:**

- lb -v 4.2.1 (generator-loopback@5.9.4 loopback-workspace@4.5.0)
- node -v v10.13.0
- OS: Windows 10 Home

### I was able to fix the issue after taking the following steps:

1. Install node v8.12.0
2. Install OpenSSL 1.1 in `C:\OpenSSL-Win64` (strong-ursa hard codes the location)
3. Create a symbolic link in `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib` named `libeay64.lib` which targets `libcrypto.lib`.
4. Run `npm i -g windows-build-tools`
5. Run `npm i -g looback-cli` again.

I'm not sure if rolling back the NodeJS version to 8.12 is necessary. There are a few widely, albeit not well documented pain points working with Loopback due to strong-ursa's use of native libraries. (Please note, this is unconfirmed information as I'm in a hurry to get back to developing the project at hand.) These steps allowed me to continue using Loopback CLI unhindered.

Useful links:

- Download previous NodeJS releases: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
- Download OpenSSL: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
- `windows-build-tools`: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools
- https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/984
- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli/issues/36#issuecomment-434331508